Не работает функция смены пароля на странице HTML/Python
В templates создал newpas.html в котором прописал:
<html>
<body>
    <table border = 1>
        <td>Имя</td>
        <td>Пароль</td>
        <td>Смена</td>
        {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
        <form action = "/changepas" method="POST">
        <td><input type = "text" readonly name = "name" value = {{row[0]}}></td>
        <td><input type = "text" required name = "pas" value = {{row[1]}}></td>
        <td><input type = "submit" value = "Сменить"></td>
        </form>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>

В Python прописал:
@app.route('/newpas')
def newpas():
    conn = mariadb.connect(
        user = 'user',
        password = 'password',
        database = 'mydb')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("Select * from mytb")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template("newpas.html", rows=rows)

@app.route ('/changepas', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def changepas():
    conn = mariadb.connect(
        user = 'user',
        password = 'password',
        database = 'mydb')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    name = request.form['name']
    pas = request.form['pas']
    print(pas)
    print(name)
    cur.execute("UPDATE mytb set pas = '{}' where name = '{}'".format(pas, name))
    conn.commit()
    return render_template('status.html', msg = "Пароль изменен")

Когда нажимаю на сменить пароль, выдаёт ошибку Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
Все остальные части программы работают нормально. Ошибка скорее всего тупая и новичковая, но я её не могу найти.



вы добавили кучу тегов к вопросу, кроме главного.

@strawdog Спасибо. Да, про него забыл.

А status.html у вас есть? вы бы дерево проекта показали бы в вопросе.

@strawdog index.html status.html show.html ну и newpas.html
